# exit status 2 when running goroutine

Tags: go

why my program panic / auto close when execute goroutine with exit status 2

```
var (
    timeout time.Duration
    ctx     context.Context
)
synchronised := usecases.NewXbaseUsecase(timeout, xbaseRepo, oodoBaseUrl, oodoDb, oodoEmail, oodoPassword, httpCl)
count := 1
gocron.Every(1).Days().At("15:54").Do(func() {
    log.Println("Start Sync")
    log.Println("Fetch ->", count)
    synchronised.SyncServices(ctx)
})
<-gocron.Start()
```

Error Message : panic: cannot create context from nil parent

```
goroutine 10 [running]:
context.WithDeadline({0x0, 0x0}, {0xe14120, 0xee6b2800, 0xe14120})
        /home/sdk/go1.17.2/src/context/context.go:436 +0x41b
```

Comment: Whatever `synchronised.SyncServices` is, it’s probably expecting a non-nil context. `ctx = context.Background()`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't given `ctx` an actual value from what I can see. Generally you would use something like `ctx = context.Background()` or `ctx = context.WithCancel(context.Background)`

There's a good article here: https://www.sohamkamani.com/golang/context-cancellation-and-values/